# Module not specified after updating Intellij 2019.1

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

After updating IntelliJ IDEA from 2018.3.4 to 2019.1 I get a `Module not specified` when trying to run my test java test scripts.

I also get the following error trace when trying to build:

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:358)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
            ...
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
...
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
            ... 34 more
```

Comment: Did you try to refresh the project in the gradle tab?

Comment: I refreshed it, but my build.gradle file is all grayed-out.

Comment: You could try remove IDE related data (.iml files and .idea folder) and reimport project from Gradle

Comment: try with File -> Invalidate cache and Restart and click on Invalidate cache and Restart button. It will will clear caches and rebuild the project

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain That worked, thanks. Why that happens? Do you know if it is a known issue?

Comment: @MateMrše this wiki has the detail https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Cleaning_System_Cache.html

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain Would you care to expand and write your solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure is it a bug or not but many people complaint the same. For me following step worked fine.

On the main menu choose `File -> Invalidate cache and Restart` and click on `Invalidate cache and Restart` button. It will will clear caches and rebuild the project on the next startup